# I just need to turn solution of JavaScript problem into Python code using the same approach

Tags: python, string, hashmap, anagram

I'm stuck on turning this JS anagram problem into Python solution using the same approach.
Here is the problem:

[image: Here the problem:]

Here is the JavaScript solution:

```
    if (first.length !== second.length) {
        return false;
    }

    const lookup = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
        let letter = first[i];
        // if letter exists, increment, otherwise set to 1
        lookup[letter] ? (lookup[letter] += 1) : (lookup[letter] = 1);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < second.length; i++) {
        let letter = second[i];
        // can't find letter or letter is zero then it's not an anagram
        if (!lookup[letter]) {
            return false;
        } else {
            lookup[letter] -= 1;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

console.log(validAnagram('anagram', 'nagaram'));
```

And here is my Python code using the same approach:

```
    if len(first) != len(second):
        return False

    lookup = {}

    for char in first:
        letter = first[char]
        if lookup[letter]:
            lookup[letter] += 1
        else:
            lookup[letter] = 1

    for char in second:
        letter = second[char]
        if not lookup[letter]:
            return False
        else:
            lookup[letter] -= 1

    return True


print(valid_anagram("anagram", "nagaram"))
```

This is the error I'm getting when I run my Python solution:

```
letter = first[char] TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to pass in a string to get the index instead of passing in an integer.

```
first = "hello"
for char in first:
      print(char)
```

Output:

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

To get the index use this:

```
for char in range(len(first)):
   print(char)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Here is a simpler solution

```
def valid_anagram(str1, str2):
    list_str1 = list(str1)
    list_str1.sort()
    list_str2 = list(str2)
    list_str2.sort()

    return (list_str1 == list_str2)
```

Comment: I apprecaite your solution and help, but I'm trying to do the same solution as the one in JavaScript approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the same solution, that uses `dict` to count letters like your Java code:

```
from collections import Counter

def valid_anagram( str1, str2 ) :
    return Counter(str1) == Counter(str2)
```

testing:

```
>>> valid_anagram('anagram', 'nagaram')
True
>>>
```

---

I wrote below, and I write here again, the whole point of using python is not reinventing the wheel and use existing libraries to make the code compact, fast and easy to understand.

Take for example your code:

```
for char in first:
    letter = first[char]
    if lookup[letter]:
        lookup[letter] += 1
    else:
        lookup[letter] = 1
```

This can be rewritten as:

```
lookup = dict()
for letter in first:
    if lookup[letter]:
        lookup[letter] += 1
    else:
        lookup[letter] = 1
```

Or, better yet:

```
lookup = Counter()
for letter in first:
    lookup[letter] += 1
```

Or, even better:

```
lookup = Counter( first )
```

So why waste time and space....

Comment: It's JavaScript by the way. Can you do it the same as Javascript code without using import or modules, just pure regular for loop and if elif statements.

Comment: @AbdifatahAli the whole point of using python is not reinventing the wheel and use existing libraries to make the code compact, fast and easy to understand.

Comment: @AbdifatahAli added to the answer